# Nightwatch js concurrent tests dependent upon login test

Tags: nightwatch.js, acceptance-testing, saucelabs

I am setting up my end to end (acceptance) testing, but have a question in regards to chaining tests.
All of my tests will be dependent upon an initial login test.  Obviously if the test user successfully logs in, then do the other tests. After logging in, I'd like to run several other tests concurrently if possible. The other tests do not need to be linear (the test user just needs to be logged in). 
How should I structure my tests for this?

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom class-style command as described about 2/3 down [this page](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands).

The guts of the command are the prototype definition, which (in my case) looks something like this:

```
Login.prototype.command = function(user, pass) {
    this.api
        .url(host + '/auth/login')
        .waitForElementVisible('#user', 2000)
        .setValue('#user', user)
        .setValue('#password', pass)
        .submitForm('#login', function() {
            self.emit('complete');
        });
```